# Removing superview in objective-c

Tags: iphone, uiview

I'm looking through an example in the iPhone Beginning programming book and they have code to switch between two views when a button is pressed.  Here's the first snippet from their example code:

```
if (self.yellowViewController.view.superview == nil)
{
    if (self.yellowViewController == nil)
    {
        YellowViewController *yellowController =
        [[YellowViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YellowView"
bundle:nil];
        self.yellowViewController = yellowController;
        [yellowController release];
    }
    [blueViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view insertSubview:yellowViewController.view atIndex:0];
}
else
{
    if (self.blueViewController == nil)
    {
        BlueViewController *blueController =
        [[BlueViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BlueView"
bundle:nil];
        self.blueViewController = blueController;
        [blueController release];
    }
    [yellowViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view insertSubview:blueViewController.view atIndex:0];
}
```

It does make sense to me, but the question I have is, how would you do this with a UISegmentControl that has four views.  I know you can check for the selectedSegment and create that view when needed.  But how would I know what the last view was in order to remove it from the superview beforing adding my new view as a subview?  Thanks!

Comment: Proper indentation would make this code much more easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check to see which view is allocated or not nil and then remove.

```
 if (yellowController) {

 [yellowController.view removeFromSuperView];
 [yellowController release];

 }
```

You could go through your four views to determine which one is loaded and then remove the view.

Answer (score 1):

while creating each view either code or IB set tag value to segmentIndex.so u can get them later by that tag value.this is tricky and simple.

Comment: In this scenario, would I need to keep track by having an ivar remember what the last view was that was selected?  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

For any `UIView` the frontmost subview is `[[myView subviews] lastObject]`.

Comment: ... and very dangerous. The framework or your own code might put some other views on top of it at any time later. Don't place time bombs in your code.